# Cannot find module './config.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, node-modules

I want to make a module linked to a config.json located outside the node_modules folder. The problem is that my index.js located in modules can't take into account the config.json located outside node_modules, do you have any idea what I should do?

I have tried

```js
let configFile = require('./config.json')
```

and

```js
let configFile = require('.../config.json')
```

Comment: "index.js located in modules" did I read that right? do you mean node_modules?

Why is your index.js in node_modules? also if that is my mistake, can you please share the project structure?

Comment: yes it's that and it's not a mistake, I want to create a module and the name is index.js but I use the module in my script

Answer (score 2):

It is important to first locate where the *'distance'* of your `index.js` file to your `config.json` file.

Say, for example, if your file tree is like this:

```
cool-bot / modules / index.js
cool-bot / config.json
```

You could have your index.js file like this:

```
let configFile = require('../config.json')
```

`../` will look up to the parent of the parent of your current folder.
`./` will look up in the current folder.

Hope this was useful for you.

Comment: heyy, my module is:  cool-bot  /  node_modules  /  cool-project  /  index.js

Comment: @Sans that is hilarious hahah You can try with `../../config.json` if the json is located on the root of the project folder

Answer (score 0):

Okay first of all I have one question. Why? Why would you put your index.js in node_modules?

Anyways, you should check how far the bot config json file is from your index.js, for example:

```
v RootProjectFolder
⠀⠀config.json
⠀⠀v node_modules
⠀⠀⠀⠀v bot_folder
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀index.js
```

`config.json`'s parent folder is `RootProjectFolder` 
`index.js` is 3 folders away from RootProjectFolder; 
`RootProjectFolder -> node_modules -> bot_folder -> index.js`
so you will need to go 3 folders back:
`./` = 1 folder back (folder in which the file is in) 
`../` = 2 folders back (parent folder of the folder in which the file is in)
`../../` = 3 folders back

So in this situation, you would do:

```js
const configFile = require('../../config.json');
```

I can't give a specific answer based on your situation as I don't know your
project's structure.